# Finding out unknown voltage using mesh analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, network

How to find out the voltage v3 in the following circuit using mesh analysis?
[image]

I tried to solve it by considering the dependent current source as a super mesh and eliminated it.

The equations I got are:

```
8 - 6*i1 + 2*i2 +3*i3 = 0 ------------ this equation belongs to the loop that contains 80 V source.
30 - 70*i3 + 50*i1 -20*i2 = 0 --------- this belongs to the loop that contains 30 V source.
15* i1 - i2 + i3 = 0 --------- super mesh equation
```

The current values I got after solving the equations are:

```
i1 ~ 0.95A
i2 ~ 11.35A
i3 ~ -2.9A
```

which translates to `V3 = 40 * i3 = 116 V`

But the solution in the book says `V3 = 104.2 V`

Can somebody please tell me where did I go wrong?

Comment: Homework questions with no attempt at a solution are closed.

Comment: @LeonHeller Can you please help me now?

Comment: You are missing 0's in all terms in first equation.  8 becomes 80, etc.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat That doesn't change the outcomes of the equations. I checked it just now.

Comment: Yeah I realized afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTilrs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Applying KVL on Mesh 1** :

```
80 = 10i1 + 20(i1–i2) + 30 (i1–i3)
80 = 10i1 + 20i1 - 20i2 + 30i1 - 30i3
80 = 60i1 – 20i2 – 30i3... ... (1)
```

**Applying KVL on the Supermesh :**

```
30 = 40i3 + 30(i3–i1) + 20(i2–i1)
30 = 40i3 + 30i3 – 30i1 + 20i2 - 20i1
30 = 70i3 – 50i1 + 20i2 ... ... (2)
```

**Applying KCL at Node1** :

```
15i1 = i3 – i2
i3 = 15i1 + i2 ... ... (3)
```

**Solving (1), (2) and (3) :**

```
i1 = 0.583 A
i2 = -6.15 A
i3 = 2.6 A
```

**Result :**

```
v3 = 40 * i3
v3 = 104 V
```

Comment: I have the same answers.